# How to get texts from screen displaying an "ABAP List"

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am able to enter to the operation in SAP GUI via VBA but I am unable to find how to select or copy the value of these fields.

While recording the script via SAP GUI, copying the fields into the clipboard won't appear in the script as an action.

Any help or reference is highly appreciated.

Please find code and screenshot below (screen of type "ABAP List").

```
Sub XXXX()
Call SAPConnections
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "Operation"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_MATRL").Text = "PartNumber"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 8
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[1]").Press
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen you are showing is named an "ABAP List".

An ABAP List is not like a general screen. Visually speaking, this is an ABAP List (monospaced font only):

[image]

And this is a general screen (labels using proportional font):

[image]

An ABAP List has fields which are not identified by their field names but by their positions. NB: consequently, the Technical Information is of no help for ABAP Lists to identify the fields.

An ABAP List may contain labels, text fields and checkboxes, they belong to the property `Children` of the [`GuiUserArea object`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=GuiUserArea), their IDs are made of prefix `lbl`, `txt` and `chk` followed by the column and row numbers, and they correspond respectively to the SAP GUI Scripting objects `GuiLabel`, `GuiTextField` and `GuiCheckBox`. For example:

- label at column 0 (first column) row 12 (object `GuiLabel`):

  ```
  /app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/lbl[0,12]
  ```
- text field at column 22 row 12 (object `GuiTextField`):

  ```
  /app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txt[22,12]
  ```
- checkbox at column 0 row 0 (first row) (object `GuiCheckBox`):

  ```
  /app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/chk[0,0]`
  ```

I guess other simple graphical elements objects like `GuiButton`, `GuiComboBox`, `GuiCTextField`, `GuiRadioButton`, etc., are not possible in ABAP Lists.

If you want to know all the fields which are in an ABAP List, you must loop at the property `Children` of the `GuiUserArea` object, as explained below.

This script loops at all the fields in an ABAP List:

```vb
text = ""
For Each field In session.findById("wnd[0]/usr").Children
    text = text & field.CharTop & " " & field.CharLeft & " " & field.Text & " " _
                & field.Id & " " & field.Type & chr(10)
Next
msgbox text
```

For the ABAP List above (first screenshot), the script will show:

[image: SAP GUI Scripting contents of ME49 Detail Screen]

The loop goes from top to bottom and from left to right. You can't just look at the fields of one row, but you can stop looping after a given row:

```vb
If field.CharTop > 2 Then
  Exit For
End If
```

As previously said, each field can be of type [`GuiLabel`](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiLabel&product=sap_gui_for_windows), [`GuiTextField`](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiTextField&product=sap_gui_for_windows) or [`GuiCheckBox`](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiCheckBox&product=sap_gui_for_windows), and has these common properties:

- `CharLeft`: horizontal position in the ABAP List
- `CharTop`: vertical position in the ABAP List
- `Text` (or `DisplayedText`)
- `Id`: the field name by its position
- `Type`: the type of object

Here is an example how to interact in an ABAP List, to position the cursor at a given column and row (`SetFocus`), and double-click (= press F2 function key/`SendVKey`):

```
column = 10
row = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[" & column & "," & row & "]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 2
```

EDIT: the below part of this answer was partially copied from this [more specific question about ME49 ABAP List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270655/vba-script-for-opening-the-quotation-of-a-particular-supplier-in-me49).

Comment: Thank you Sandra it worked wonders.

For future reference, how would I be able to find the Scripting object / prefix from different type of fields?

Comment: For ABAP lists, I think there's no other type of field (NB: I just added checkbox in the list above). You may use [`screenreader.exe`](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1441550/E) by SAP (access with your S-User), [Scripting Tracker](https://www.stschnell.de/) by Stefan Schnell, or even create your own screen reader with SAP GUI Scripting.