# How to Select all data from SAP GUI window with VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I would like to select all find results using VBA. Could you please help me for the same. Below is the actual code for two different lines.

```
session.findById("wnd[3]/usr/lbl[8,2]").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[4,8]").caretPosition = 11
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get texts from screen displaying an "ABAP List"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893797/how-to-get-texts-from-screen-displaying-an-abap-list)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/subPART-SUB:SAPMV45A:4701/ctxtKUAGV-KUNNR").text = "56987"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/subPART-SUB:SAPMV45A:4701/ctxtKUAGV-KUNNR").caretPosition = 5

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[4,5]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[4,5]").caretPosition = 18
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[4,5]").caretPosition = 13